# Use of many pointers in a function

Tags: pointers

How they have use the pointers in the function compare.

I could not understand.

Can somebody explain me this.

Function:-

```
int compare (const void *a, const void * b) 
{ 
    return ( (*(Box *)b).d * (*(Box *)b).w ) - 
           ( (*(Box *)a).d * (*(Box *)a).w ); 
}
```

Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/box-stacking-problem-dp-22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `(Box *)b` it's a casting type from void to Box struct.
2. `(*(Box *)b).d` it's a dereferencing from Box struct's pointer. So, you can handle the structure as an instance, and then get struct's fields values as `b.d`.
   Another option could be to use the pointer and avoid dereferencing with: `b->d`.

At the end, the *compare* function does: (d*w) - (d*w)'. If result were 0, then compare indicates both structures has same values.

PD. At (2): don't forget you are receiving the parameter as a pointer, and this implementation dereferences it as `(*b).d`